# How to know if I've answered another question from a user before?

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request

Is there a way that I can easily find that I'd answered of one of the questions by a particular user? Something like, I've profile ID of so call user for whom I want to know whether I'd answered for him/her before. I know that I can check this in Question tab on their profile. But there's lots many questions and also more than one answer could be possible for that question so it's not a proper way to see. Any other way?

In Facebook, we've one functionality of "we can see our friendship with particular user --- where we can see all activities done between each other."

Note:

People, *please don't misunderstand*, I really don't like or want any social functions on this beautiful network. ***I am only thinking of some way to get this information easily available to me.***

Comment: We can't remember everything we're doing on the site. Sometime we may want to check just for curiosity or other reason to check our past activity. That's it.

Comment: Today, I was checking the profile of one of the user, I am thinking that I'd given an answer to that user in past. I checked this in his profile, but then couldn't find my answer as there are lots of questions and I don't even remember which answer I'd given. But I strongly believe that I'd given an answer for him. Now I want to know which answer I'd given.

Comment: *"In Facebook, we've..."* Best reason I've heard yet for **not** having it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That's an example, I am trying to explain such kind of functionality. If you want I can edit my question though! @CodyGray

Comment: You can write an sql query for the SE data explorer to find out if you interacted with another user. This should suffice as a feature as SO is explicitly not about social interactions.

Comment: @l4mpi, That's correct! I am also don't prefer social functions on SE network. Its really beautiful without those features. I am only curious for my question, I don't really want that feature. I've no idea of how to query that on SE, though I'm waiting.

Comment: There's absolutely no need for that information, IMO. The concept here is to deal with the *question*, and not the person asking it. Vote (up or down), close, or answer the question based on it's content and merit, and quit worrying about who asked it or whether you've helped them before - it's not relevant to anything here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Where have we met before

There is an interesting script in place that can provide you with a starting point...

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/50166/where-have-we-met-before

this tool accepts the id's of two members and then produces their historical interactions on the site.  At a deeper level of inference, the presence of this script on the site is an indicator that your question is a reasonable one.