# Could we create an interaction log between users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm a modest contributor of SO and didn't use it for a while.

I just got back after more than a year, read a few answers, and found a good written one by someone who helped me a few years ago.

I know that, then, he wrote me a very good & constructive answer or comment, not recalling where or what. It brings me to my question "why can't we have an interaction log between users?"

I picture a dedicated component on the other users profile page with a list of your interactions: a topic you posted he/she answered to or the other way, common comment feeds.

I'm not sure if it has been covered or suggested already, or even if it has been implemented somehow, but I wondered. :)

Comment: maybe helpful: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258600/578411

Comment: Indeed. The comment from @Ken_White seems to have closed the discussion as a feature request: " The concept here is to deal with the question, and not the person asking it. Vote (up or down), close, or answer the question based on it's content and merit, and quit worrying about who asked it or whether you've helped them before". My use case still stands and is valid I believe, but I understand it might not be SO approach to encourage this.

Comment: Seeing the downvotes starting to stack, I must also say that I'm sorry that my question had not enough "content & merit" to avoid being stoned. That is the very reason why I stopped posting on meta. Downvote should only sanction bad written, baseless, opinionated or non-constructive questions imho. At least add a comment to explain why I should have abstained from posting.

Comment: @Billybobbonnet someone (based on lack of edits it was likely you) added "feature-request" to the post to ask for "lets implement/do not implement" votes - if it was not your intention feel free to remove the tag (also it really looks like feature request - you may want to [edit] post so it does not look like one)

Comment: This question is highly related, though not a duplicate because your question is requesting the feature, and this question is asking how to do it with existing tools: [Is there a way to find all interactions with a specific user?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373518/7795130)

Comment: Side note: recent (deleted) discussion on "some @#$@# user edited my post give me ways to track all that user did to my posts..." may taint voting here.

Comment: You do know voting on meta is different, right? And as we might have to crack some tough / unpopular nuts here doesn't affect reputation? Your kind of emotionally loaded *I'm sorry that my question had not enough "content & merit" to avoid being stoned* suggest you missed that memo ... I don't feel sorry for my [badly received answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270852/578411) either.

Comment: @rene I now understand this. I didn't know about the meta version of voting being different of the regular one. I guess I won't delete this one since it had some kind of pedagogic value. Thanks for the constructive comments & answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A feature like this turns Stack Overflow from a site oriented around Q&A into a social media platform.

### This is *highly* undesirable.

Now, one is less preoccupied with the value of the *answers*, but more with whom they've interacted with.  This is undesirable since now this gives some kind of permission - either implicit or explicit - for a person to *always* try to interact with that person to get them to answer their questions.

Comment: Don't know how an "interaction *log*" hidden inside of a menu would turn SO into a social media platform ...

Comment: @JonasWilms well, I understood it as this: Social media platforms exist to connect people. SO exists to connect users to quality Q&A.The interaction log exists to connect users. Ergo, SO would be going towards a social media-esque direction.

Comment: @script46 ah right, thats why we disable chat, delete all comments that don't use technical terms and stop every interaction with each other alltogether.

Comment: '*thats why we disable chat*' - Chat is an integral part of this site to reduce the number of comments. It allows for more off-topic discussions which might've been closed if asked as questions.'*delete all comments that don't use technical terms*' - 1. Technical terms are not necessary for it to be related to programming. 2. Yes, we actually do remove unnecessary comments, take a look at the flag reasons for comments. '*and stop every interaction with each other alltogether.*' - How would you have the Q or the A in Q&A if you removed any and all interactions?